# Styling Highcharts yAxis.title for PNG export

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) to make interactive charts. My `yAxis.title` is cut off when I export it as a PNG file (see image). I try to style the `yAxis.title` but no result. I tried it with:

```
exporting: {

            chartOptions: {
              title: {
                text: view.defaults.settings.graph.title,
                style: {
                  fontSize: '12px'
                }
              },
              subtitle: {
                text: view.defaults.settings.graph.subtitle,
                style: {
                  fontSize: '10px'
                }
              },
              yAxis: {
                title: {
                  margin: 0,
                  x: 0,
                  style: {
                    fontSize: '8px'
                  },
                }
              },
              legend: {
                enabled: true
              }
            }
```

[image]

How do I manage the styling for the PNG export?

Comment: are u using any plugin chart?

Comment: @Fiido93 The title says Highcharts.

Comment: try contact your support thx